# flot legend, how to hide yet use the color tiles

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flot

I have custom legend for my flot plot, which i added check boxes to allow a user to turn the series on and off.  The default legend has to be set to true in order for my legend to have color swatches. I am interested if there is a way to get rid of the default legend, yet retain the color swatches for my custom legend?  Below are a few snippets to show what I am doing:

```
var options = {
    legend: {
        show: true,
        container: legendcontainer,
        noColumns: 2,
        sorted: false
    },
    series: {
        points: {
            show: false
        },
        lines: {
            show: true
        }
    },
    grid: {
        hoverable: true
    },
    xaxes: [{
        axisLabel: 'Frequency (Hz)',
    }],
    yaxes: [{
        axisLabel: 'Power (dB)',
    }],
    crosshair: {
        mode: "xy",
        color: 001,
        lineWidth: .5
    }
};

$.each(results, function(key, val) {
     track = track + 1;
    val.color = i;
    ++i;
    l = val.label; 
     if (track == 1){
        temp.append(row);
        row.append(cell);
        cell.append('Left Channel');
     } else if(track == numtracks){
        row = $('<tr/>');
        temp.append(row);
        cell = $('<td width=\"100\">');
        row.append(cell);
        cell.append('Right Channel');
     } //else if ((track == 7) or (track == 14) or (track == 21) or (track == 28) or (track == 35)){

     //}

        cell = $('<td width=\"70\"/>');
        row.append(cell);
        var bar = $('<div style=\"width:18px; white-space:nowrap; float:left\"><bar />');
        cell.append(bar);
       var inp = $('<input name="' + l + '" id="' + l + '" type="checkbox" checked="checked">');
        cell.append(inp);
        var bits = $('<label>', {
                text: l,
                'for': l
                });
        cell.append(bits); 

    choiceContainer.append(temp);
```

I have tried sending the custom legend to a div that's non existent, and sending it to an arbitrarily small div, neither of which worked out.  If I set the legend to 'false' then all the swatches go away, including the ones I am using in my custom legend.  Below is an image of what I have currently rendered:

[example http://skylinedrifter.homeip.net/2.0/tmp5.jpg](http://skylinedrifter.homeip.net/2.0/tmp5.jpg)

Thanks again for the expert communities help!

Comment: I can't tell from the code posted.  If you are generating your own legend, why do you need flots built in one?  Are you cloning it's tiles?

Comment: Hey Mark,  I am cloning the tiles currently.  Most of the bits under the $.each compiles my custom legend, which is the items that start with "left channel" and "right channel".  My legend is great... but I don't know how to retain the tiles if I turn off the default legend.

A bit more.  The default legend does not give me the flexibility to group the tracks by left and right channels, etc... which is why I built my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options.

**One**, just hide the flot generated legend after you are done with building your legend.  A simple:

```
$('.legend').hide();
```

should be all you need.

**Two**, since you are already 90% of the way there, just remove your need for the flot legend entirely.  There's nothing fancy about the color 'tiles', just a `div` in a `div` in a `td`.

```
<td>
   <div style="border:1px solid #ccc;padding:1px">
       <div style="width:4px;height:0;border:5px solid rgb(175,216,248);overflow:hidden">
       </div>
   </div>
</td>
```

Just replace the `rgb(175,216,248)` with the color of the series.  If you are letting flot auto assign the colors, you can get them from the plot object's series:

```
var colorArray = $.map(myPlot.getData(), function(s){return s.color});
```

Comment: Mark, thanks for the two options..I'll give the second one a whirl and see what happens!

Comment: Mark.. I am mostly there but have an issue...  my JS code works like this:  Options, build checkboxes, render plot (and confirm status of checkboxes).  In order to get the colors out of myPlot, that occurs after the plot call, which is long after the table of checkboxes has been built.  The Plot function includes:  choiceContainer.find("input:checked").each(function() {
          var key = this.name;  Which is what requires the checkboxes to preexist.  Thoughts?

Comment: @Mark, how were you getting the tiles?  Wouldn't they also would require the plot call to be made before you built your legend?

Comment: Hey Mark, I followed the example here:  http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/series-toggle/index.html

You can see my test code here:  http://skylinedrifter.homeip.net/2.0/importPCD3.html

Comment: Mark to be fair, I have noticed a glitch somewhere in my code where the tile color grabbed does not match.. it's usually the last series.  Do you have an example of your preferred way to do the toggled data sets and such?

Comment: @Mark, here's a quick and dirty example of how I'd implement this:  http://jsfiddle.net/QEz34/

Comment: Mark, very cool!  Thank you for taking the time to help me with this issue.  I'll give it a try tonight or tomorrow hopefully and let you know how it works out.  Hope you are having a great weekend!

Comment: Mark, okay.. I am 99% of the way there.  I have a loop which does multiple plots... and as a result, only the last one toggles properly.  I have tried serializing 'seriesToggle' and 'toggle' to no avail.  Can you easily identify where I need to serialize to make the toggles plot specific?  Thanks again!

Comment: Mark, the root issue is that the labels repeat on each plot... that is.. I am plotting power spectrums for audio files.. so each plot has a track one left and right.. 1L and 1R for example.

Comment: @Mark, if the labels aren't unique enough to find the curve, then introduce another property that is.  Here, I've given each series an id property:  http://jsfiddle.net/QEz34/1/

Comment: Mark.. we are close.  But that does not help.  I have placed the js routine in a function and it is called three times from the page, passing the results, the placeholder and the legendholder.  This results in 3 plots on the page, but the last one is the only one the toggling works on.  You see it live here:  http://skylinedrifter.homeip.net/2.0/importPCD3.html  It seems something is interfering with the earlier plots working properly once a new plot has been created.

Comment: @Mark: I've edited your code, see here: http://pastebin.com/yKxzgRR4, I removed the need for an `id` series attribute and just did it with indexes.

Comment: Mark.. it looks like you fixed it.  Thank you for your patience and support!  I really appreciate the help!  My strengths are not javascript...just half a dozen other languages anymore.